# Ansible: Why is a rescued task not marked as failed at the end of the of the playbook?

Tags: ansible

I have the following playbook (or at least censored but the main idea):

```yaml
- name: run command based on condition 
  block:
    -name: run command based on condition 
     command: *some curl command*
     when: * condition*
     register: out
     failed_when: 'rc != 0'

     debug: var=out
  
  rescue:
    - name: Set flag
      set_fact: flag="failed"
      when: "'FAILED' in out"
```

This runs 3 times based on 3 conditions, based in the block section, and depending on the component it can skip the first, second and 3rd.

Now, according to Ansible documentation:

> *If an error occurs in the block and the rescue task succeeds, Ansible reverts the failed status of the original task for the run and continues to run the play as if the original task had succeeded. The rescued task is considered successful and does not trigger `max_fail_percentage` or `any_errors_fatal` configurations. However, **Ansible still reports a failure in the playbook statistics.***

At the moment, for test purposes i have one failure set up. using the above, it is rescued. However, at the end I have:

```yaml
failed=0 ... rescued=1
```

How can I have the `failed` counter increase as well?

This iteration of playbook is after having some more hacky with `ignore_errors: true` that marked the failed tasks as ignore but after doing more research I found out that block/rescue/always is more efficient.

At some point I had used `any_errors_fatal` in my variables and also in my block.

Comment: "_How can i have the Failed counter increase as well?_", not out-of-box and without implementing or changing code and as far as I know. Maybe this [How to use blocks and rescue in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-block-rescue) helps out to work around ...

Comment: @U88D Perhaps the page that I took the excerpt above is not valid anymore?

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#block-error-handling

Here it is, not sure why there is conflicting information.

Comment: Ansible will not run `debug` or any other following task, it will fall back to `rescue` block. Also, your `failed_when: 'rc != 0'` will never make the task failed (as you need to check `out.rc` instead) and in fact it's not even needed because it will get failed automatically on non-zero return code.

Comment: @CruceruMalin, the documentation page is actual and about `rescue`, whereby your question is mostly about playbook statistics and summary.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev the real fail condition is ' out.rc != 0 ' , I just forgot the "out." when writing this post.

Comment: @U880D apologies, perhaps I not the best choice of words.

My failed block is rescued and counted as rescued in the playbook statistics. However, it is my understanding from the page and that paragraph specifically that the failure should be counted as well in the statistics. 

In my case, it is not and I would like to change that and I am not sure why.

Comment: "_specifically that the failure should be counted as well in the statistics_", no, and that's what also the examples on [Handle exceptions in Ansible Playbooks with block and rescue](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-block-rescue) show. A rescued task will not count as failed. And it shows how to deal with that by using `_result_fail`.

Comment: @U880D I believe that the problem is that the documentation referred above is really a bit confusing with that _Ansible still reports a failure in the playbook statistics_ line. Since there is no example log output, one could expect the failed counter to be increased in the play recap as well, however in reality this line only means that the task will be marked as rescued.

Comment: @AlexanderPletnev, right, there is no example log output. But if even in that case, we could also assume that everyone knows that only Schroedingers cat can be in two states at the same time, `failed` and `rescued`, but not an Ansible task. The same for `skipped`, `ignored`, `unreachable`, some are mutual exclusive ... "_Ansible still reports a failure in the playbook statistics_", no, it doesn't, as one can see from my [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Overall it's  good question in order to get familar with `block`, `rescue`, results and task statistics.

Answer (score 1):

Q: ***"Increase failed counter."***

A: When a task fails, the registered variable is not available in the *rescue* section. Use [ansible_failed_result](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#handling-errors-with-blocks) instead. For example, increment a *rc* list

```yaml
    - block:
        - command: "{{ my_command }}"
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            rc: "{{ rc|d([]) + [ansible_failed_result.rc] }}"
```

Display `CUSTOM STATS`. See [SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/config.html#show-custom-stats). Use the module [set_stats](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/set_stats_module.html#ansible-builtin-set-stats-module-define-and-display-stats-for-the-current-ansible-run) to declare what you want to display. For example, the number of failed tasks per host

```yaml
    - set_stats:
        data:
          failed: "{{ rc|d([])|length }}"
        per_host: true
```

---

- Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03

  vars:

    cmd:
      test_01: ['true', 'false', 'false']
      test_02: ['true', 'true', 'false']
      test_03: ['true', 'true', 'true']

  tasks:

    - block:
        - command: "{{ cmd[inventory_hostname].0 }}"
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            rc: "{{ rc|d([]) + [ansible_failed_result.rc] }}"

    - block:
        - command: "{{ cmd[inventory_hostname].1 }}"
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            rc: "{{ rc|d([]) + [ansible_failed_result.rc] }}"

    - block:
        - command: "{{ cmd[inventory_hostname].2 }}"
      rescue:
        - set_fact:
            rc: "{{ rc|d([]) + [ansible_failed_result.rc] }}"

    - set_stats:
        data:
          failed: "{{ rc|d([])|length }}"
        per_host: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS=true ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_01 : ok=4    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=2    ignored=0   
test_02 : ok=4    changed=2    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0   
test_03 : ok=4    changed=3    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


CUSTOM STATS: ********************************************************************************
    test_01:   failed: '2'
    test_02:   failed: '1'
    test_03:   failed: '0'
```

---

- The above example keeps blocks in the code to enable the testing of the rescue sections. It's much easier to demonstrate the functionality of *custom stats* without blocks. For example,

```yaml
shell> cat pb.yml
- hosts: test_01,test_02,test_03

  vars:

    cmd:
      test_01: ['true', 'false', 'false']
      test_02: ['true', 'true', 'false']
      test_03: ['true', 'true', 'true']

  tasks:

    - command: "{{ item }}"
      register: out
      failed_when: out.rc < 0
      loop: "{{ cmd[inventory_hostname] }}"

    - set_fact:
        rc: "{{ rc|d([]) + out.results|map(attribute='rc') }}"

    - set_stats:
        data:
          rc: "{{ rc | join(',') }}"
          failed: "{{ rc | select('>', 0) | length }}"
        per_host: true
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
shell> ANSIBLE_SHOW_CUSTOM_STATS=true ansible-playbook pb.yml
  ...
PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************
test_01 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_02 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   
test_03 : ok=3    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0   


CUSTOM STATS: ********************************************************************************
    test_01:   failed: '2'  rc: 0,1,1
    test_02:   failed: '1'  rc: 0,0,1
    test_03:   failed: '0'  rc: 0,0,0
```

Answer (score 0):

What you've observed is the expected behavior.

> ***How can I have the `failed` counter (*annot.: in the `PLAY RECAP`*) increase as well?***

You can't for that counter, at least not without implementing something or changing [`play_iterator.py`](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/executor/play_iterator.py) and as far as I know.

A minimal example playbook

```yaml
---
- hosts: localhost
  become: false
  gather_facts: false

  tasks:

  - name: Main block
    block:

      - debug:
        failed_when: true

    rescue:

      - debug:
```

will result into an output of

```yaml
TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! =>
  msg: Hello world!

TASK [debug] *****************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: Hello world!

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=1    ignored=0
```

because a `rescued` task is not a `failed` task as it became rescued. This [mentioned in the already referenced documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbook_guide/playbooks_blocks.html#block-error-handling)

> *If an error occurs in the block and the rescue task succeeds, Ansible reverts the failed status of the original task for the run and continues to run the play as if the original task had succeeded. The rescued task is considered successful and does not trigger `max_fail_percentage` or `any_errors_fatal` configurations.*

But you can have other, additional counters. The article [How to use blocks and rescue in Ansible](https://www.redhat.com/sysadmin/ansible-block-rescue) shows how to collect, classify and display such other kind of task related result set.

**Follow Up Reading**

- [Ansible Issue #79711 - *`PLAY RECAP` Incorrectly Considers Failures as Rescues in Block Rescue*](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/79711)