# gitlab-ci to trigger a merge request if the ansible-playbook resulted in "changed>0"

Tags: ansible, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Gitlab pipeline which executes an ansible-playbook which would create an inventory file. Now, if the playbook resulted in `changed>0`, there should be a merge request with the changes to the `main` branch.

Below is my `gitlab-ci.yaml`,

```
---
include:
  - local: .gitlab-ci-vars.yml

image: 
  name: $ANSIBLE_IMAGE
before_script:
  - ansible --version
stages:
  - "inventory build"
  - create_merge_request

inventory-build:
  stage: inventory build
  script:
    - ansible-playbook $PLAYBOOK_NAME 
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG

# Proceed with MR only if the playbook resulted in some changes
create_merge_request:
  stage: create_merge_request
  script:
    - echo "Creating merge request..."
    # Use GitLab API or custom scripts to create the merge request here
```

I don't want to pipe the output of the playbook and check for `PLAY RECAP` to identify if there is a change in the inventory. There must be some better approach to it that I am not aware of. I am using gitlab `v16.7.3-ee`

Comment: "_I don't want to pipe the output of the playbook and check for ..._" since [there are no Exit Codes for your Use Case](https://jwkenney.github.io/ansible-return-codes/) I am afraid you have to parse and analyze some kind of generated output.

Comment: Maybe you can use the [`counter_enabled` callback – adds counters to the output items (tasks and hosts/task)](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/counter_enabled_callback.html) or [`CUSTOM_STATS` shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77955351/6771046).

Comment: Finally ended up doing the `grep` from ansible output, not very impressed but it serves the purpose.

Answer (score 2):

It will get simpler if you do it from the playbook itself. Any Ansible task produces a return object containing `changed` flag. If it's registered into a variable, it can be used in any subsequent action.

So, if you're talking about the inventory being changed, you probably have a task that writes the inventory file to the filesystem, so you can reuse that task's result.

`counter_enabled` and custom stats mentioned by [@U880D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6771046/u880d) in the comments will allow to conveniently aggregate the changes per host into one variable, so if you want to control the behavior based on some specific number of changes, you can do that. But the overall solution remains the same.

You can also run Git with `command` module to check if the workspace has been modified after the checkout or differs from the target branch, register its output, and apply `changed_when` task keyword to define the condition that marks the task result as changed - I do the same when I retrieve the data from VMware API and construct the inventory dynamically.

Alternatively, if you don't want to raise the merge request from Ansible itself, the simplest solution I see is to write a file that contains something like `changed: true` or `changed: false` to the workspace and use it instead of parsing Ansible logs (which could be duplicated to files using `community.general.log_plays` callback plugin, by the way). Or just run that `git diff ...` or other comparison command and analize its output.

P.S. Note that by default some modules (such as `command`, `shell`, `raw`, and maybe some others) are not idempotent, so they always return `changed: true` unless reconfigured.

Comment: I have modified the code to check the status of `git diff`.

Answer (score -1):

Below is my modified version of the `gitlab-ci`

```
inventory-build:
  stage: inventory build
  script:
    - |
      ansible-playbook $PLAYBOOK_NAME   
      git diff --exit-code --quiet ## status of git diff doesn't work sometimes. 
      if [ -z "$(git status --short)" ]
      then 
        echo "No change to the inventory" 
      else
          echo "Change detected in the inventory, going to create a merge request" 
          git checkout -b ci_processing ## If we want the change to be pushed to the same branch, delete/comment this line
          git config user.email "project_,<project-id>_bot_<random-uuid>" ## https://forum.gitlab.com/t/project-email-access-token-is-not-a-project-team-member/89311
          git config user.name "ci-bot"  
          git remote add gitlab_origin https://${CI_PROJECT_NAME}:${PROJECT_ACCESS_TOKEN}@$CI_SERVER_HOST/$CI_PROJECT_PATH.git
          git add .
          git commit -m "Inventory push back from the pipeline"
          # git push gitlab_origin HEAD:$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -o ci.skip # push to the same branch without an MR
          git push gitlab_origin ci_processing -o merge_request.create -o merge_request.target=$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH -o ci.skip # prevent triggering pipeline again
      fi  
  tags:
    - $RUNNER_TAG
```

I followed The recommendation from Alex to do a `git diff` and act based on the output of the diff.

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution would be only suitable for one specific playbook, and even in this case it's not safe. Generally, a play recap can have much more lines than 5, and even if it has less, there could be more than one containing `changed=0`. There could also be false positives when there are failed tasks.